How to show infx∈D⟨p,x⟩>supy∈Ω⟨p,y⟩?
Suppose thet $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ is closed convex, and $ D \subset \mathbb R^n$ is compact convex. If $\Omega \cap D = \varnothing$, then please show$\exists p \in \mathbb R^n$ with $inf_{x \in D}\langle p, x \rangle \gt sup_{y \in \Omega} \langle p, y \rangle$.
My idea is: We can find $x_0$ such that $\langle p, x_0 \rangle = inf_{x \in D}\langle p, x \rangle$, since D is compact. However I don't know how to measure the "distance" between p and y.
What'more, I want an example to show the inequality fails if D is closed convex but not necessarily bounded.

Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

check out theorems that give existence of separating hyperplanes

Suppose $p \notin \Omega$. Then the set of all distances (actual distance, not inner product) from $p$ to points $y\in \Omega$ is bounded below by $0$, So it has an infimum, and since $\Omega$ is closed, there is a $y_0$ which gives that distance. By convexity, the hyperplane perpendicular to $p - y_0$ and passing through $y_0$ has $\Omega$ on the opposite from $p$. I.e., for all $y \in \Omega, \langle y_0-p, y\rangle \ge 0$.

$\exists x_0$ such that $\langle p,x_0 \rangle = inf_{x\in D} \langle p, x \rangle, \forall x \in D$.
Then we let $y^*$ be the closest vector in $\Omega$ to $x_0$, since $\Omega$ is cloesd.
By closest point thoerem, we have $\langle x_0 - y^* , y - y^* \rangle \le 0, \forall y \in \Omega$, since $\Omega$ and D are convex.
let $p = x_0 - y^*, p \neq 0$, since $\Omega \cap D = \varnothing$. Then we get $\langle p, y - y^* \rangle \le 0$.
So, $\langle p, y \rangle \le \langle p, y^* \rangle, \forall y \in \Omega$
let $\alpha = \langle p, y^* \rangle$,
$\langle p,x_0 \rangle - \alpha = \langle p, x_0 - y^* \rangle = \langle x_0 - y^*, x_0 - y^* \rangle = \Vert x_0 - y^* \Vert ^2 \gt 0$
So, $\langle p, x_0 \rangle \gt \alpha \ge \langle p, y \rangle, \forall y \in \Omega $
Finally, we get $inf_{x \in D} \langle p, x_0 \rangle \gt sup_{y \in \Omega} \langle p, y \rangle$.
